# Is it possible to invoke Mahout's spark item-similarity job from Java/Python?

Tags: apache-spark, mahout-recommender

I am new to recommender systems and trying to decide between Apache Mahout and Spark ALS as the algorithmic core for my recommender engine.

Does Mahout's spark item-similarity job only have a cli?

The only related documentation that i have come across is this: http://apache.github.io/mahout/0.10.1/docs/mahout-spark/index.html#org.apache.mahout.drivers.ItemSimilarityDriver$ which pertains to the cli.

Also, for the the cli, I see that the input format is limited to text files. Does that mean I will have to transform all my data, stored in say Cassandra, to a txt file format to use spark item-similarity?

I have already referred to the introductory documentation on usage of spark item-similarity here - https://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/intro-cooccurrence-spark.html.

Any help and pointers to relevant documentation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage find something on this?

Comment: No I didn't. Ended up using Spark.